# How to get formatted text in Nic Editor while Pasting content?

Tags: javascript

I need to get only the content without the styles while copying from excel and pasting it in to the Nic Editor. How can I achieve it?

Comment: But I am using latest version of Nic Editor. In some cases I need only default font size and other styles like bullets, numbering are should be same as copied contents. Is is possible to get like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NicEditor (version 0.9) doesn't have any code related to handling pasted content. It relies on mechanisms of [contenteditable](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) attribute. Checkout the brain-dead-simple example here http://jsfiddle.net/WLPbY/

Paste some styled content in the div from the example above - you'll see that it's styled and it looks just like it does when pasted to NicEditor (and all of that by just adding `contenteditable` attribute to a div).

As to how to solve your problem - you could try acting on [paste event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuimtmq.php) to act on data pasted to get it and strip from any unwanted styles.